# How to eliminate false results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use bigquery to extract data about 10 most mentioned personalities in the leading newspapers in Israel using this code:

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `composed-hold-309910.dataset_1.israel_media_person`

GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

Unfortunately, some of the results iv'e gotten were not actual people but some "buzzwords" like 'Maccabi Haifa' and 'Gaza Gaza'

| person | count_mentions | count_distinct_urls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benjamin Netanyahu | 32965 | 20660 |
| ------------------ | ---------------- | -------------------- |
| Maccabi Haifa | 16528 | 5947 |
| ------------------ | ---------------- | -------------------- |
| Gaza Gaza | 13267 | 7623 |

I would be delighted to find a way to eliminate these false results.

Matan

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out these buzzwords by using where person not in ([list_buzz_word])